# Efficient way to calculate sum(a.*exp(b.*c),1) using MATLAB's GPU functionality

Tags: matlab, performance, optimization, gpu, gpgpu

I have GPU accelerated MATLAB code that spends 80%-90% of its time computing

```
sum(a.*exp(b.*c),1)
```

where

```
size(a) = [n 1]
size(b) = [n 1]
size(c) = [1 m]
```

**n** can be chosen to be arbitrarily large (within memory constraints)

5000 < **m** < 20000

I'd like to speed this up by more than just using gpuArrays (approx 17x for double precision).

### Benchmarking

Using MATLAB 2018b and an NVIDIA P100 GPU, I have run the following script aiming to find the optimal size of **n**. It shows that I achieve a 17x speedup compared to CPU (Dual socket Intel Xeon E5-2650v2) using double precision. Can I improve on this by doing something more advanced, like using GPU coder, or even shared memory or texture memory as described in the following?
https://uk.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/examples/accessing-advanced-cuda-features-using-mex.html

```
%% Optimisation MWE

nVec = 1000:1000:60000; % Vector of candidate n values
m = 5000;

f1 = figure(1);
ax(1) = subplot(3,1,1);
ax(2) = subplot(3,1,2);
ax(3) = subplot(3,1,3);

% Preallocate time outputs
t = nan(length(nVec),3);
speedupGPU = nan(length(nVec),2);

% Loop over candidate n values
for n = 1:length(nVec)

    %% CPU code
    a = rand(nVec(n),1);
    b = rand(nVec(n),1);
    c = rand(1,m);

    f1 = @() sum(a.*exp(b.*c),1);

    t(n,1) = timeit(f1,1);

    %% GPU code (double precision)
    a = gpuArray(a);
    b = gpuArray(b);
    c = gpuArray(c);

    f2 = @() sum(a.*exp(b.*c),1);

    t(n,2) = gputimeit(f2);

    %% GPU code (single precision)
    a = single(a);
    b = single(b);
    c = single(c);

    f3 = @() sum(a.*exp(b.*c),1);

    t(n,3) = gputimeit(f3);

    %% Calculate speedup
    speedupGPU(n,1) = t(n,1)/t(n,2);
    speedupGPU(n,2) = t(n,1)/t(n,3);

    %% Plot
    plot(ax(1),nVec,t,'.-')             % Plot compute time
    plot(ax(2),nVec,t./nVec(:),'.-')    % Plot normalised compute time
    plot(ax(3),nVec,speedupGPU,'.-')    % Plot Speedup

    %% Label plots
    xlabel(ax(1),'n')
    ylabel(ax(1),'Time')
    legend(ax(1),'CPU','GPU double','GPU single')

    xlabel(ax(2),'n')
    ylabel(ax(2),'Normalised Time')
    legend(ax(2),'CPU','GPU double','GPU single')

    xlabel(ax(3),'n')
    ylabel(ax(3),'Speedup')
    legend(ax(3),'CPU/GPU double','CPU/GPU single')

    drawnow

end
```

This results in the following figure (top: Execution time with increasing n (smaller is better), middle: Execution time normalised by n (smaller is better), bottom: speedup relative to CPU (larger is better)):

[image: Execution time, normalised execution time, and speedup over various **n**]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realize it might not give you the speedup you're looking for, but one way to make this code more performant is to get rid of the `sum` by using matrix multiplication:

```
sum(a.*exp(b.*c),1) --> a.'*exp(b.*c)
```

On my system this resulted in a speedup increase from ~10 to ~15.

I should also mention, that for the lowest value of `n`, I got a ~20 speedup by also replacing the array multiplication (`.*`) with matrix multiplication (`*`):  `a.'*exp(b.*c) --> a.'*exp(b*c)`.

Tested on R2019b, Win10, GTX660.

Comment: Maths > Hardware

Comment: Great improvement! I guess the bottleneck of speed comes from the expensive `exp()`, maybe some reformulate of that will give remarkably higher performance...

Comment: Nice idea! On my desktop (R2018b, Win10, GTX960) getting rid of the sum as you suggest gives a more modest speedup improvement of ~13 vs ~12 with my original code. On this hardware replacing the element-wise multiplication by matrix multiplication is actually detrimental, giving a speed-up of 9. I'll now check on the P100.

Comment: @B.Thomas I too noticed the detrimental effect of the 2nd action, an exception to which was the smallest `n` - which is what I mentioned. As hinted by Thomas, I'd expect that approximating the exponent (e.g. Taylor series expansion) will give you some speedup (by sacrificing some precision). Depending on your application, this might be a viable strategy too. A quick google search revealed this relevant 2015 paper: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/272178514_Fast_Exponential_Computation_on_SIMD_Architectures

Comment: @Dev-iL On the P100, the second action does actually give an incremental benefit over the first action over all tested values of n. I'm seeing an improvement from ~17x to ~20x with your suggestions, which I'll gladly take. I also suspect Thomas is right - I'll take a look.

Comment: @B.Thomas It is possible that the GPU somehow doesn't handle implicit expansion too well, and by replacing it with matrix operations this problem is avoided. Other that, I'm happy to hear that this helps. BTW, texture memory is probably irrelevant, because you're not accessing the same memory/variable repeatedly.

Comment: If the limiting factor is the exponentiation (which it most likely is) then I agree. I had wondered if the b.*c part would benefit from storing the vectors b and c in texture memory, since each element of each row of the resulting matrix are computed using the same element of b (and therefore it would need to be fetched multiple times).
I guess it depends how it's implemented underneath?

Comment: I would imagine that MATLAB's implementation is quite optimized. Other than that, determining the bottleneck should be possible this using an appropriate profiler (such as the one in [Intel Parallel Studio](https://software.intel.com/en-us/parallel-studio-xe) or the [NVIDIA Visual Profiler](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-visual-profiler), but this will not be easy).

Comment: Yes, I would imagine so for something as ubiquitous as multiplication. Interestingly, the result of my original code and the optimised version differ slightly (of the order of n*eps). I suspect the optimised version is also the more accurate of the two, but I'm by no means certain. 
Thanks for your help, I'm happy to mark as answered.